# Can ServletRequest#getLocale return null?

Tags: java, servlets

The documentation is not very explicit for this:

Can `ServletRequest#getLocale` ever return `null`? Is it possible that the server does not have a locale specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for this method to return null. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocale%28%29):

> Returns the preferred Locale that the client will accept content in,
>   based on the Accept-Language header. If the client request doesn't
>   provide an Accept-Language header, this method returns the default
>   locale for the server.

The default Locale of the server would be the default Locale of the JVM (unless you have overridden it), which can never be null.